# replace a particular word in string

Tags: java, string, replace

Suppose these are some URLs,

```
http://www.example.com/conditions/redirecting/home/ovc-20197858
http://www.example.com/conditions/gotos/definition/sys/ovc-20197858
```

now what i want to replace the url's word **home** with **place-for-you** if url consist home and **definition** with **place** if urlcontains  **definition**. For this i wrote a code but its not changing the url.

```
String newurl = "";
String url = "http://www.example.com/conditions/redirecting/home/ovc-20197858";
String home = "home";
String definition = "definition";
             boolean check = url.matches("home");
// already tried boolean check = url.contains("home");

             if(check == true)
             {
             newurl = url.replace(home,"place-for-you"); 
             }
             else
             {
          newurl = url.replace(definition,"place"); 
             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#matches()` is something that you use with [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)

you need to use contains instead:

```
boolean check = url.contains("home");
```

example:

```
if (url.contains("home")) {
        newurl = url.replace(home, "place-for-you");
```

Edit:[image]

Comment: i dont know why it was not working when i applied the same but i copy pasted your code and it start working...! thanks :)

Comment: BUT BUT it is not working for  if (url.contains("definition")) {
                 newurl = url.replace(definition, "place");
             }

Comment: I see, but you need another string for that??

Comment: do again another if after the 1st one :)

Comment: That is what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

**No need to check if your String contain that string or not**, `replace` will do that :

```
url = url.replace("home", "place-for-you");
url = url.replace("definition", "place");
```

because replace will check if the input contain this string ten replace else it will not replace it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the `matches` method you will see that the string you pass it's supposed to be a regular expression. In your case you are passing `boolean check = url.matches("home");` Your URL is different than `"home"` so it will always return false. If you want to do this with regular expression you need to change this line to `boolean check = url.matches(".*home.*");` In regular expression `.*` means any character 0 or more times.

If you want to just check if the String `"home"` exists I'd suggest changing the whole line to `boolean check = url.contains("home");`

It definitely works - run the following Junit test for yourself:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String newurl = "";
        String url = "http://www.example.com/conditions/redirecting/home/ovc-20197858";
        String home = "home";
        String definition = "definition";
        boolean check = url.matches(".*home.*");

        if(check == true)
        {
            newurl = url.replace(home,"place-for-you");
        }
        else
        {
            newurl = url.replace(definition,"place");
        }

        assertEquals(newurl, "http://www.example.com/conditions/redirecting/place-for-you/ovc-20197858");
    }
```

Comment: i already did but it is not working i think its not about finding word in string its about finding pattern becuase its a URL and it is whole one string

Answer (score 0):

Kindly keep in mind that String is immutable, so you can't change it. 
So best approach would be using StringBuilder instead like

```
String newurl = "";
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("http://www.example.com/conditions/redirecting/home/ovc-20197858");
        String home = "home";
        String definition = "definition";
        if (url.indexOf("home") != -1) {
            url.replace(url.indexOf("home"), url.indexOf("home") + 4, "place-for-you");
        } else {
            url.replace(url.indexOf("definition"), url.indexOf("definition") + 10, "place");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this method to check if Home exist or not.

```
public class Algo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newurl = "";
        String url = "http://www.example.com/conditions/redirecting/home/ovc-20197858";
        String home = "home";
        String definition = "definition";
        boolean check = url.contains("home");

        if (check == true) {
            newurl = url.replace(home, "place-for-you");
        } else {
            newurl = url.replace(definition, "place");
        }
        System.out.print(newurl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example,

```
import java.util.*;
public class demo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String newurl = "";
    String url = "http://www.example.com/conditions/redirecting/home/ovc-20197858";
    String home = "home";
    String definition = "definition";
             boolean check = url.contains("home");

             if(check == true)
        newurl = url.replace(home,"place-for-you"); 
             else
        newurl = url.replace(definition,"place"); 

    System.out.println("Old URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("New URL : " + newurl);
    }
}
```